# override a zend library

Tags: overrides, zend-framework

i'm trying to override a zend library (Zend_Pdf_Page) and it doesn't seem to be working. i'm putting it in app/code/local/Zend/Zend_Pdf_Page.php, but the parent class is being used instead.

are there any configuration changes i need to make to get it to work?

thanks!

laura

Answer (score 21, accepted):

all Zend classes are instantiatet directly, for example here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/ShipmentController.php:726
$page = new Zend_Pdf_Page($xSize, $ySize);
```

This is the reason you can't use any config.xml syntax to change the class itself with an `<rewrite />`

But the include path is set as expected:

```
/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:...
```

Therefore putting a Zend class in the correct path (yours is wrong) should do the trick:

```
app/code/local/Zend/Pdf/Page.php
```

Comment: I stand corrected... :) Good to know!

Comment: If it is working and my answer helped, you are welcome to mark it as solution :)