# Magento 1.9.1.0 Admin panel date in Finnish

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0

I updated Magento to the 1.9.1.0 version and noticed that in Finnish the admin panel date on the upper right corner shows each day in "cccc". When I change the language the date is normal, for example today it's "Friday, 6 March 2015" but when I change to Finnish, the date is "cccc 6. maaliskuuta 2015". I'm not sure where this should be translated, but at least the "translate.csv" does not affect the cccc. It's a small issue but would be nice to have fixed, so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The date formats are defined in the `Zend_Locale` library module. The language file Suomi / Finnish ([`fi.xml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/fi.xml#L1804)) is the only one containing the erroneous date format pattern `cccc d. MMMM y` whereas all other ones are set to `EEEE, d. MMMM y` or similar.

The pattern was [introduced with a commit](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/commit/f30750360eb86daab529caaf33cb7712c9cd38b1) in ZF 1.12.4 (so CE 1.9.0.1 is not affected).

To fix this temporarily, you can [copy the `Zend_Locale` module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1129/22855) to e.g. `app/code/local` and modify the XML file there (duplicating a subset of the module should do, copying only the language file will not). Log out, clear caches, log in, *perjantaina*!

Additionally, you might isolate the problem and file an issue at the [ZF's GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1).

**UPDATE:** The locale data [turned out to be an external library to ZF](https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues/562#issuecomment-102934372), so this is not within the ZF collaborators' area of responsibility.